# How to query the distribution (grouped by value range) of a column value in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose there is a table called DISTANCES in Oracle with a float type column named distance. The range of distance is from [0, 1000]. I want to know the distribution of the distances, for example, how many rows are in each of the following ranges: (0, 10], (10, 50], (50, 100], (100, 500], ... (5000, 10000].

How can I build this SQL query?

Comment: Please show the complete definition of your table (ideally as `create table`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a derived table to put each distance into its group. Then `GROUP BY` and `count`:

```
select dist_group, count(*)
from
(
 select case when distance between 0  and 10 then '(0, 10)'
             when distance between 10 and 50 then '(10, 50)'
             ...
             when distance between 5000 and 10000 then '(5000, 10000)' end as dist_group
 from distances
) dt
group by dist_group
```

Comment: Your sql works perfectly. One further question, what if I want to know the percentage of each group at the same time?

Comment: I'm not an Oracle user, but I think they have nice functionality for that. Anyway, in ANSI SQL you can simply add "count(*)* 100.0 / (select count(*) from distances)" to the select list.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN   0 <= distance AND distance <=   10 THEN distance END ) AS in_range_0_10,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN  10 <  distance AND distance <=   50 THEN distance END ) AS in_range_10_50,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN  50 <  distance AND distance <=  100 THEN distance END ) AS in_range_50_100,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN 100 <  distance AND distance <=  500 THEN distance END ) AS in_range_100_500,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN 500 <  distance AND distance <= 1000 THEN distance END ) AS in_range_500_1000
FROM   Distance;
```